# How to transfer Checkbox parameters in Django Materialized view?

Tags: python, html, django, materialize

The setup contains Django with Materialize view library.

Two questions:

1) How to transfer parameters from html to .py -file when using Materialize checkbox?

2) If this works, then how to keep them in a session so that when next time visiting on page, the checkboxes are not empty?

I have googled a lot and made many trials with no success.

Library:  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css"

homepage.html:

```
<form action="#">
     {% for sites in wsites %}
        <label >
            <input type="checkbox" name="option{{sites.id}}" id="option{{sites.id}}" value={{sites.id}}/> 
            <span>{{sites.name}} </span>
        </label> 
        <br>
     {% endfor %}
</form>
```

views.py

```
def homepage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.POST) 
    return render(request = request, 
                  template_name='main/home.html', 
                  context = {"wsites":Sites.objects.all })
```

Session parameters is an empty list, ie. print(request.POST) = []. I would appreciate to get some help how to resolve this.